# Android app recorded video can not open any external player. error is can't play this link

Tags: android, android-studio, file, video, internal-storage

I just want to play a recorded video play in MX Player or other external player using intent.

but the player can not play the video. it gives an error like "Can't play this link"

Here is my code for get the file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TPVideos/" + videoRecordingList.get(position).getVideoFile().getName());
            Log.e(TAG, "File: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID ,file);

            intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

This is my meta-data in manifest file

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.roshan.telepromptervideoapp"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

This is my filepaths.xml file

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="my_docs" path="." />
<external-path name="external_files" path="TPVideos/" />
```

[hear is my directory from where I get the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B13JB.png)

Comment: Do you think it's a problem is with your code or problem with video? Not obvious if... **(1)** Does your code work okay for all other MP4 files, just not this problematic one file? If YES then problem is with video file. If NO then problem is with code. **(2)** Without using code... Does the file play when opened in some media player, or is it a corrupted data?

Comment: Without code file is working perfectly